Try to create a react native expo app but keep failing
This summer I start my mobile app project. I tried to create a react native expo app by typing npx create -expo-app [Project name] in the terminal. I already checked that node, npm, and npx are installed correctly on my computer. The node is also included in the path of the environment variable. However, PowerShell keeps giving me this error:
PS C:\Users\FirstName LastName.....> npx create -expo-app ProjectName

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL

npm ERR! Could not install from "LastName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\40336" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\FirstName LastName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-04T09_12_26_081Z-debug.log

I observe that in the second line of Error, the URL starts at my LastName, so maybe it is because I have a space between by user name so the system can enter the path. I try to use softLink to delete the space between but it does not work. I also tried to create a new user in my computer which does, but the error still holds the same. can anyone help me to solve that?

Well what's the error when you try to install to a directory without a space?

The error message still appears to be the same no matter using the soft link or creating a project under another Windows user that does not have space in between.

You can try this below
npm cache clean --force
then
npx create -expo-app FitAllies

Thank you for replaying, It says npm warn using --force Recommended protections disabled.

then what happened when you npx create -expo-app FitAllies now?

shows the exact same error code

try this npm cache verify @Zzz99045

It says Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
